# Proving that a term by term series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was looking at examples for a series such that $\sum {a_n}$ converges, but $\sum {a_{3n}}$ diverges here in the website, and I saw the following examples:

First one:

> $ a_{3n-2} = \frac{1}{1+4(n-1)} ,a_{3n-1} = \frac{1}{3+4(n-1)}, a_{3n} = -\frac{1}{2n}$. This > series converges to $\frac{3}{2} \log(2)$. But, $\sum {a_{3n}}$ diverges.

Second one:

> $$1+0+(-1) + \frac{1}{2} +0 +\frac{-1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} +0 +\frac{-1}{3}+\cdots $$
> The series converges to $0,$ while $\sum a_{3n} = -\infty.$

I get why the series $\sum a_{3n}$ converges, but I have a hard time understanding why the original term by term series converges.
Anyone can explain briefly?

Comment: It is possible to construct an easier example: $a_{3n+1}=a_{3n+2}=-{1\over n+1},\ a_{3n}={2\over n+1}.$ The series is convergent to $0,$ as the partial sums are of the form $s_{3n}=0,$ $s_{3n+1}=-{1\over n+1}$ and $s_{3n+2}=-{2\over n+1}.$ In general $| s_n|\le {6\over n}.$

Answer (score 0):

The convergence of a series $\sum a_n$ is defined via the convergence of the sequence of its partial sums $s_n:=a_1+\dots+a_n$. Thus if you consider e.g. the series $\sum a_{3n}$, its partial sums are not a subsequence of the partial sums of the original series (though it may look like that at first sight) and the convergence of one is in principle not related to the convergence of another.

If we leave out unnecessary zeros from your second example making it thus clearer, we get
$$1-1+\frac12-\frac12+\frac13-\frac13+\dots$$
Now consider $\sum a_n$ and $\sum a_{2n}$. The partial sums of the "full" series form the sequence $1,0,\frac12,0,\frac13,0,\dots$ which clearly goes to $0$. The "omitted" series is just the divergent (negative) harmonic series.